# Gathering Customer Location from a website

Tags: html, wordpress, frameworks

I want to gather the customer location from my wordpress website to deliver the products.
How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [GEO my WordPress](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/geo-my-wp/#installation) ([How to install](https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/geo-search-post-types-wordpress/))? This is a plugin that can be used for acquiring geolocation, mapping and proximity search. It uses the features of the Google Maps API and OpenStreetMaps.

#### Sources:

1. https://docs.geomywp.com/article/172-current-location-shortcode;